# jwplayer onSetupError for invalid license key

Tags: javascript, error-handling, jwplayer6

I'm using jwplayer's html5 player for mobile. Our license key expired today and while we renew the key, I want to handle this gracefully. I tried to use the `onSetupError` callback to do this. I have the following setup :

```
jwplayer.key = "key";
jwplayer("selector").setup({
    file : "file",
    advertising : {//ad block}
});
jwplayer.onSetupError(function (event) {
    //Handle the error.
});
```

When I try to run this I get the following error:

> There was a problem setting up the player:   (jwplayer.js, line 4)
>   message: "Error setting up player: Invalid license key"
>   type: "jwplayerError"
>   version: "6.8.4616"
>   **proto**: Object

This error is expected, however the onSetupError callback is not being called. Is there something wrong with my setup and if so what should I change in this?